# Windows 10 stuck in boot loop with windows auto repair. wont boot from usb or cd

Tags: boot, windows-10

specs - asrock gen 3, 2500k, nvidia 960, 16 gig ram.

So computer wont boot and goes into constant repair or gets stuck in load and eventually says "inacessable boot device" "Machine_check_exception"

I have tried booting off a windows 8 cd & tried booting the windows 10 usb and none seem to load.

Strangely enough I unplugged by ssd hard drive to try get the usb to boot and it is still trying to load windows 10..

Is there some sort of motherboard memory I can erase? I tried removing battery and updated bios but still no luck

Comment: Its odd that this question is tagged windows 10 but the user says "they tried booting off a windows 8 cd".  

I think they are generally trying all the documented recovery tools from 2016 era windows 10 systems and getting nowhere, just like a million other helpless users, like me, in fact, as an informal IT helper for lots of people, I see this a lot. Windows 10 is a pile of trash when it comes to recovery from boot failures.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 shipped in a lot of different "build" numbers and the recovery options available to you depend both on that, and on the tools provided by whoever made your motherboard (in your case) or your laptop (in case of another random person on the internet googling and finding your old question).

Ie, for you, asrock, for other readers, their maker, such as dell, hp, and lenovo may have more specific help for recovery.

Windows 10 cannot be rated highly for ease of use in this case.  Accessing Safe Mode when the system won't boot is mostly a matter of just keeping on powering off your computer after it's had 10 minutes to boot and hasn't booted.

Eventually what they replaced safe mode with, an automatic repair process, kicks off.

Dozens of times, I have also done this, and automatic repair has never actually automatically repaired anything. Some kind of manual repair might be possible, but I have never found a workable way to repair a Windows 10 system.

There are usb boot options, and this question shows this user tried to operate all of those. None of them can do much for you. You can't uninstall updates from these emergency boot to command prompt modes, and there's no longer any way to boot to a safe mode gui and remove updates in windows 10.

The old thing you knew as "Safe mode" is in fact only accessible to you if your system will already boot up.  It is no longer safe mode anymore.

In no way, in 2020 is anything like "safe mode" even accessible to you as a regular person, from a system that won't even boot. What we have here instead is some kind of ceremonial vestigial memory of safe mode.

Safe mode is dead, and Microsoft killed it. What's left of it doesn't count, because you can't use it when it's needed.

There are usb-based recovery methods some people who google this question later, should perhaps be trying, such as booting up from an external recovery usb stick, instead of following the dead-end path of trying to find some sort of safe mode boot option (pressing F8 or something like that that used to work, in windows 7 and has been more or less removed from modern systems).

The recovery methods you have may lead you to a dead end. If that is so, make sure you start using a backup tool after this, so that you can then move from using Microsoft's recovery tools, to using your backup tool's full recovery options, and recover your last backup onto a fresh hard disk, after pulling your broken hard disk out.

It would be super nice if Microsoft provided a way to report broken systems and send the broken unbooteable configuration details to them, so they could detect major bugs and flaws in their systems and repair them, but Microsoft does not have these tools.

Answer (score -1):

If you installed a device driver recently then try this: restart your computer, enter `Advanced Boot Options` menu, select the `Last Known Good Configuration` option. You may boot Windows 10 into Safe Mode and try a system restore or a Rollback.